# Standard Deviation for Times

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, time, date-math

Is there a T-SQL coding best practice to get an accurate standard deviation value for a group of times? `STDEV` doesn't like the `time` data type.  I'm thinking that maybe a conversion to minutes as an integer, but a conversion from/to what?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert a `time` value to a corresponding number of desired time units by using the `DATEDIFF()` and [`DATEDIFF_BIG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql) functions:

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST('00:00' AS time), YourTimeColumn) AS Minutes

DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST('00:00' AS time), YourTimeColumn) AS Seconds

DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, CAST('00:00' AS time), YourTimeColumn) AS Milliseconds
```

Basically, you are just obtaining the difference, in the given units, between the timestamp of `00:00:00.0000000` and your time value.

You can put the entire expression inside `STDEV`:

```
STDEV(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST('00:00' AS time), YourTimeColumn))
```

That, of course, will give you the deviation in minutes.  If you need to convert it back to `time`, you can do it by applying `DATEADD()` to the `STDEV` result:

```
DATEADD(
  MINUTE
, CAST('00:00' AS time)
, STDEV(
    DATEDIFF(
      MINUTE
    , CAST('00:00' AS time)
    , YourTimeColumn
    )
  )
)
```

The final expression becomes quite cumbersome this way.  You can try simplifying it by defining some of the intermediate expressions as columns.  One way is to use `CROSS APPLY`.  For instance, here is how you can define and use a temporary computed column for the `DATEDIFF` result:

```
SELECT
  ...
  DATEADD(MINUTE, CAST('00:00' AS time), STDEV(tmp.TimeMinutes)) AS TimeStDev,
  ...
FROM
  dbo.YourTable AS data
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST('00:00' AS time), data.YourTimeColumn)
  ) AS tmp (TimeMinutes)
  ...
WHERE
  ...
;
```